# Check error log in NVDA

Tags: python, screen-readers, error-log, nvda

How can I check errors in my code using NVDA error log? I've created an addon, which seemingly doesn't works due to some error. How can I debug my code using error log or any other method possible?

The error I'm facing is in the following code:

```
import globalPluginHandler
import ui
import versionInfo
from NVDAObjects.window.scintilla  import Scintilla

class GlobalPlugin(globalPluginHandler.GlobalPlugin):
  def _messag(self, gesture):
    ui.message("notepad++ opened") # speak hello when notepad++ is the current screen

  def chooseNVDAObjectOverlayClasses(self, obj, clsList):
    if obj.windowClassName == u'Scintilla' and obj.windowControlID == 0:
       clsList.insert(0, self._messag)
```

Comment: Why isn't there a `__gestures = {...}` statement as in the developer guide example?

Comment: Gesture should only be there when I am giving some input via keyboard. However, here I am speaking a message when Notepad++ becomes the active window

Comment: In the developer's guide, they insert a class in `clsList` instead of a bound method. Can't you try to do the same? Also, if nothing happens, it could be because the callback is not bound to an event.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about NVDA, but when python programs fail, they do it by raising an exception. You could perhaps include a mechanism to catch these exceptions and send them to a file. For example let's take a plugin from the [NVDA developer's guide](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/developerGuide.html)

```
--- start ---
# Version announcement plugin for NVDA
# Developer guide example 2

import globalPluginHandler
import ui
import versionInfo

class GlobalPlugin(globalPluginHandler.GlobalPlugin):

    @MY_EXCEPTION_CATCHER
    def script_announceNVDAVersion(self, gesture):
        ui.message(versionInfo.version)

    __gestures={
        "kb:NVDA+shift+v": "announceNVDAVersion",
    }

--- end ---
```

I added a decorator to the code that catches the exceptions that may occur and displays them in an html file that can be displayed in browser for example

```
import functools
import cgitb
import sys

def MY_EXCEPTION_CATCHER(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            with open('exception.html', 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write(cgitb.html(sys.exc_info())
            raise
    return wrapper
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What didn't work? You may need to adapt the path to the exception.html file, or apply the decorator to other functions in the plugin's class.

Comment: Tried that. But the raise and return keywords become unusually highlighted in the editor. Also after running the code, I see no difference.

Comment: The only difference, if there was an exception during the decorated callback, would be that you have a file `exception.html` somewhere (you could give a full path for this file). Also if you want to check that the callback gets actually executed, you can try to raise an exception in the callback itself, such as `raise RuntimeError('Hello there')`